# Visual Studio 2012 - There is an error in XML document (0,0) when trying to close the program

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I"m getting this weird error when I try and close Visual Studio 2012 or do a publish to the Azure cloud. It comes up with an alert box that says "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)" and won't let me close the program and I have to end process in order to exit. It also appears when I right click the cloud project and select publish from the context menu. I am able to package the project however. Which I find odd.

Any ideas at all on what could be the issue? I tried re-installing both VS and Azure SDK and I still receive the error. I also uninstalled my extensions and I'm still receiving the error. Not really sure what to do about it.

**EDIT**

I'm only having this issue in VS2012. I can open the same project in VS2010 and not have any issues closing the program or publishing it to Azure

Comment: Do you have any XmlSerialization in your project?

Comment: maybe it will help you: http://teamreview.codeplex.com/workitem/7153

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi I have no idea what XmlSerialization is. I work in a TFS environment and my instance of VS is the only one with this issue and it does it no matter what project I currently have open.

Comment: as i mentioned this link http://teamreview.codeplex.com/workitem/7153 is about similar error in project that use TFS environment.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi IF that is the solution I am unable to access that directory because of Corp. Policy they have the Documents and Settings folder locked on our machines. I will post back later after I hear back from IT

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi I haven't heard back from IT yet. But I am only having this issue in VS2012. I have VS2010 installed as well and there aren't any errors when trying to close the program or publish to Azure

Comment: Sorry i have no idea.